# Want to clarify my complex plane sketch shaded regions are correct or not

Tags: complex-numbers

Want to clarify my complex plane sketch shaded regions are correct or not,

$-12 < Im( z-8i) < -4 $  ∪ $  -12 < Re( z-8) <  -4$

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem correct to me.One thing you can do is to wrrite $z=x+iy$,  then sketching the graph would be easier.

Comment: The general shape is right but it is in the wrong location.  As RXV suggested, start by writing $z=x+iy$.

Comment: @RamanujanXV Did you mean like this sir, \begin{array}{l}
-12< Im( x+iy-8i) < -4\\
-12< y-8< -4\\
-4< y< 4\\
\\
-12< Re( x+iy-8) < -4\\
-12< x-8< -4\\
-4< x< 4
\end{array}

Comment: -12<Im(z-8i)<-4 for (0, 8) and -12<Re(z-8)<-4 for (8, 0); is this wrong location @David

Comment: @RGen Exactly..That's the correct answer.